# Записать текст на русском в таблицу MySQL

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

Здравствуйте, хешкодеры!

Обрисовываю ситуацию, которую не могу решить: есть PHP код в файле utf8. Есть apache2, php5, mysql. Сопоставление кодировки соединения с MySQL: utf8_general_ci. Есть таблица с поле типа TEXT с сравнением utf8_general_ci, но когда происходит попытка записи в эту таблицу из файла-скрипта PHP в utf8 все ровно происходит сохранение в сбитой кодировке. Не знаю в чем проблема. Уже вроде все комбинации перепроверил. Через терминал с подключение к MySQL вбивать правильные данные получается, сохранение происходит нормальное, но программно никак...

Спасибо за внимание. Если нужны уточняющие данные или скрипты, предоставлю.

P.S. Мутно как-то описал все. Так яснее: нужно программно через код PHP сделать запись текста на русском в таблицу mysql.

Comment: @Алексей Данчин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну так попробуйте перед вашими запросами написать:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Comment: Вот бывает странные моменты в программирование. Я пробовал этот метод, но не работал. Так бы сюда с таким вопросом не лез. Но вот попробовал еще раз и О ЧУДО все заработало. Спасибо =)))

Comment: Вместо mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); советуют использовать [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php)